# Problem after upgrading from 10.04 to 11.10 on a Mac

Tags: 11.10, 10.04, upgrade, launcher

I've just upgrade from Ubuntu 10.04 to 11.10 on my Mac(OS X) but after it has restarted, it would not open after selecting the Ubuntu launcher. I have a black screen with a flashing bar and cannot do anything else en ubuntu. The partition that has Mac is fully functional. What can I do to recuperate the ubuntu partition and make it work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Even if I am sure you have done it already, my first advice would be to wait even longer to see if the boot process works after a longer time. Then, what happens when you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>?

Are you able to run a Live CD of Ubuntu? This would permit you to get your data back and to repair your installation.